# How to get UIButton from a Xamarin.Froms.Button?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uibutton, custom-renderer

I'm using Xamarin.Forms mixed with some native Xamarin code. Now I'd like to get a UIButton instance from a Xamarin.Forms.Button. How can I do that?

In the `Clicked` event handler, I can see

```
    void Share_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Xamarin.Forms.Button;
        if(button.EffectControlProvider != null)
        {

        }
    }
```

I can see EffectControlProvider.Controller is actually of UIButton type but I can't convert to it.

Is there any funciton like ToNative to get the UIButton?

Comment: Is this code within a PCL or .NET Standard library or within your platform specific project?

Comment: Please refer the this link this might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Referring to Native Views from Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml#referring-to-native-views-from-code).

```
#if __IOS__
    var wrapper = (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NativeViewWrapper)contentViewButtonParent.Content;
    var button = (UIKit.UIButton)wrapper.NativeView;
    button.SetTitle("Scale and Rotate Text", UIKit.UIControlState.Normal);
    button.SetTitleColor(UIKit.UIColor.Black, UIKit.UIControlState.Normal);
#endif
```

Notice:this code is only used in `Shared Access Project`.